# How to force R not to set a refference in ordinal data in coxph

Tags: r, ordinal, cox-regression

I am modeling Cox regression and some of my independent variables are ordinal data and have trouble with the reffernce groups.

By default the coxph package takes the first group in a variable as a refference group, i.e. in the vaiable female/male the female group is the refference. However, I have an ordinal variable with three levels (1, 2, 3). I do not wish a refference group in this ordinal variable but I want R to give a total estimate for my total variable.

Answer (score 0):

What about `as.numeric(your123factor)` ? then R will treat your variable as continuous.

Comment: My varibales has three levels, but every level covers a count. My variable df$count looks like this: 1. 1, 2. 2, 3. >2. Will as.numeric function violate this?

Comment: @Daniel so maybe `as.numeric(substr(df$count,1,1))` ?